# Two selection box and get the result of selection in a box

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

Need your help in PHP/SQL so i have a select box that it works well but what i need is when i select something i need to have the whole parameter related to my selection in a multiple selection box for example if i select `router 1` i have in router 1   `interface 1 
            interface 2
            interface 3`

so i want to select one of these interfaces of router 1 and have the result of selection in a box for example like this `router 1 : interface 1`
This is my php code of the first selection:

```
$query = "SELECT nom FROM collectes";



// Execute it, or let it throw an error message if there's a problem.

$stmt = $pdo->query( $query );
$dropdown = "<select name='collectes'>";

foreach ($stmt as $row) {

  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['nom']}'>{$row['nom']}</option>";

}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

echo $dropdown;
```

Comment: check, after the dropdown: `if (!empty($_POST["collectes"]) {  //Show the other select box here. }`